# type conversion for templates

Tags: c++, templates, type-conversion

I have a wrapper class template and want to have implicit conversion to the wrapped type in order to use existing library functions:

```
#include <complex>

double f(double x) { return 1.; }

template <typename T>
std::complex<T> f(std::complex<T> x) { return std::complex<T>(); }

template <typename T>
class A {
  T _x;
public:
  A(const T& x) : _x(x) {}
  operator T() { return _x; }
};

int main() {
  A<double> da(1.);
  A<std::complex<double>> ca({1.,1.});
  f(da); // OK                                                                                                                  
  f(ca); // error                                                                                                               
  return 1;
}
```

The `f(std::complex<T>)` is not used for `f(ca)` because implicit conversion is not considered during template argument deduction (see the generated error msg. [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b8cc6faf4d5ba232)).

In the real code `f(...)` is replaced by library functions e.g. from the `<complex>` header, so it can't be modified.

If I inherit `A` from `T` (as suggested by the error message) then `f(ca)` compiles. But then `A` is not defined for built-in types (you can't inherit from them). Also, that would give all the functionality of `complex<double>` to `A<complex<double>>` which I want to avoid.

Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: There's always `template<class T> T f(A<T> x) { return f(static_cast<T>(x)); }`, but that can also get annoying quite fast.

Comment: Shouldn't it be operator const T& () const and operator T& ?

Comment: Thanks, and I agree. I'd like to be able to use all library functions accepting `complex<T>`, and that's a lot.

Comment: Is explicit conversion -- e.g. having a `toComplex()` function -- really so offensive? Just curious, since in my personal experience, implicit conversions have created at least as many problems as they have solved.

Comment: I want to calculate very complicated expressions in physics. The idea is to have a syntax as close to normal paper and pencil calculations as possible in order to avoid mistypes.

Comment: Are there more than a few dozen functions you need this to work with?  It seems ... strange that you want *every* function to work, while not eanting `complex<T>` methods.

Comment: Probably not, so I can just take all functions from the <complex> header and use the solution given by T.C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To resolve the "doesn't work for built-in types" problem, you can use a template specialization. The `std::complex<>` version uses inheritance.

```
template <typename T>
class A {
  T _x;
public:
  A(const T& x) : _x(x) {}
  operator const T &() const { return _x; }
  operator T &() { return _x; }
};

template <typename D>
class A<std::complex<D>> : public std::complex<D> {
  typedef std::complex<D> T;
public:
  A(const T& x) : T(x) {}
};
```

If inheritance is not acceptable, the only approach I am aware of is to define functions that take `A<>` as an argument. However, you can simplify the task by defining the functions within `A<>` itself, and thus leveraging a simplified syntax for the template argument, and argument dependent lookup for function call invocation.

```
template <typename T>
class A {
  T _x;
  friend A f(A x) { return f(x._x); }
public:
  A(const T& x) : _x(x) {}
  operator const T &() const { return _x; }
  operator T &() { return _x; }
};
```

Comment: "... that would give all the functionality of `complex<double>` to `A<complex<double>>` which I want to avoid." ?

Comment: @Barry: I was only resolving the inheritance of built-in types issue. As a workaround to the problem at hand, it answers the question.

Comment: This now works for both types, but the other problem (unwanted funcionality from complex) remains.

Comment: @jxh Thank you for the new suggestion. Actually I wanted to solve the problem once and forever, even is someone comes up with a new function of a complex number. But this will probably not happen too often. The other solution I can think of is creating a non-template implementation for complex, and then the original code works fine.

Comment: Would that mean you would implement `float` versions too?

Comment: @jhx I only thought of implementing the double version, as I always use double. But that is not a good solution either, because the problem is that library functions for complex numbers are actually templates, and therefore implicit conversion will not work. So I have to define functions taking A<>. I have chosen the global version in the very first comment by T.C. and provided a preprocessor macro. This will make it possible to adapt new functions to the code without going into the details. (However, this will not help in the case of functions with more than one arguments.)